# Glow material isn't working

Tags: materials

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpWWYEF59lo. And the glow doesn't work. Here's a screen shot[image] Any ideas?
Thx, Dave

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the emission colour to a brighter shade, and maybe change the shading from smooth to flat. Otherwise, just continue with the vid!

Comment: Also, since the floor is almost exactly a complementary color to the glow, it won't show much.

Comment: I've tried all that.

Comment: OK, BA found it. https://blenderartists.org/t/glow-material-isnt-working/1115374/7